# increase debian server VM system partition while server is running

Tags: debian, partition

i have a debian 8 webserver VMware VM that runs out of HDD space.
i increased the HDD Size in VMware.
then i wanted to add the unallocated space to the system partition.
i am not very familiar with linux so i tried a few things but i didnt got it done.

output of fdisk -l:

```
root@WebserverLinux:/# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 80 GiB, 85899345920 bytes, 167772160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x28bb70d9

Device     Boot    Start       End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048  80383999 80381952 38,3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       80386046  83884031  3497986  1,7G  5 Extended
/dev/sda3       80384000  80386045     2046 1023K 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       83884032 167772159 83888128   40G 8e Linux LVM
/dev/sda5       80386048  83884031  3497984  1,7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

sda1 should be extendet with the space from sda4 while server is running.

any ideas?

EDIT: Here is what i did according to the answer of Zoredache, can i write this to disk without dataloss? (Hyperviser snapshot made but i would like to avoid using it)

```
root@WebserverLinux:/home/ruko# swapoff -a
root@WebserverLinux:/home/ruko# fdisk /dev/sda
[32m
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.25.2).
[0mChanges will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): m

Help:
[1m
  DOS (MBR)
[0m   a   toggle a bootable flag
   b   edit nested BSD disklabel
   c   toggle the dos compatibility flag
[1m
  Generic
[0m   d   delete a partition
   l   list known partition types
   n   add a new partition
   p   print the partition table
   t   change a partition type
   v   verify the partition table
[1m
  Misc
[0m   m   print this menu
   u   change display/entry units
   x   extra functionality (experts only)
[1m
  Save & Exit
[0m   w   write table to disk and exit
   q   quit without saving changes
[1m
  Create a new label
[0m   g   create a new empty GPT partition table
   G   create a new empty SGI (IRIX) partition table
   o   create a new empty DOS partition table
   s   create a new empty Sun partition table


Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1-5, default 5): 5

Partition 5 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1-4, default 4): 4

Partition 4 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1-3, default 3): 3

Partition 3 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1,2, default 2): 2

Partition 2 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 1
Partition 1 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 1
First sector (2048-167772159, default 2048): 
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-167772159, default 167772159): 164274175

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 78,3 GiB.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (1 primary, 0 extended, 3 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (2-4, default 2): 2
First sector (164274176-167772159, default 164274176): 
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (164274176-167772159, default 167772159): 

Created a new partition 2 of type 'Linux' and of size 1,7 GiB.

Command (m for help): t
Partition number (1,2, default 2): 2
Hex code (type L to list all codes): l

 0  Empty           24  NEC DOS         81  Minix / old Lin bf  Solaris        
 1  FAT12           27  Hidden NTFS Win 82  Linux swap / So c1  DRDOS/sec (FAT-
 2  XENIX root      39  Plan 9          83  Linux           c4  DRDOS/sec (FAT-
 3  XENIX usr       3c  PartitionMagic  84  OS/2 hidden C:  c6  DRDOS/sec (FAT-
 4  FAT16 <32M      40  Venix 80286     85  Linux extended  c7  Syrinx         
 5  Extended        41  PPC PReP Boot   86  NTFS volume set da  Non-FS data    
 6  FAT16           42  SFS             87  NTFS volume set db  CP/M / CTOS / .
 7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT 4d  QNX4.x          88  Linux plaintext de  Dell Utility   
 8  AIX             4e  QNX4.x 2nd part 8e  Linux LVM       df  BootIt         
 9  AIX bootable    4f  QNX4.x 3rd part 93  Amoeba          e1  DOS access     
 a  OS/2 Boot Manag 50  OnTrack DM      94  Amoeba BBT      e3  DOS R/O        
 b  W95 FAT32       51  OnTrack DM6 Aux 9f  BSD/OS          e4  SpeedStor      
 c  W95 FAT32 (LBA) 52  CP/M            a0  IBM Thinkpad hi eb  BeOS fs        
 e  W95 FAT16 (LBA) 53  OnTrack DM6 Aux a5  FreeBSD         ee  GPT            
 f  W95 Ext'd (LBA) 54  OnTrackDM6      a6  OpenBSD         ef  EFI (FAT-12/16/
10  OPUS            55  EZ-Drive        a7  NeXTSTEP        f0  Linux/PA-RISC b
11  Hidden FAT12    56  Golden Bow      a8  Darwin UFS      f1  SpeedStor      
12  Compaq diagnost 5c  Priam Edisk     a9  NetBSD          f4  SpeedStor      
14  Hidden FAT16 <3 61  SpeedStor       ab  Darwin boot     f2  DOS secondary  
16  Hidden FAT16    63  GNU HURD or Sys af  HFS / HFS+      fb  VMware VMFS    
17  Hidden HPFS/NTF 64  Novell Netware  b7  BSDI fs         fc  VMware VMKCORE 
18  AST SmartSleep  65  Novell Netware  b8  BSDI swap       fd  Linux raid auto
1b  Hidden W95 FAT3 70  DiskSecure Mult bb  Boot Wizard hid fe  LANstep        
1c  Hidden W95 FAT3 75  PC/IX           be  Solaris boot    ff  BBT            
1e  Hidden W95 FAT1 80  Old Minix      
Hex code (type L to list all codes): 82

Changed type of partition 'Linux' to 'Linux swap / Solaris'.

Command (m for help): a
Partition number (1,2, default 2): 1

The bootable flag on partition 1 is enabled now.

Command (m for help):
```

Output requested by DerfK:

```
root@WebserverLinux:/# pvscan
bash: pvscan: Command not found.
root@WebserverLinux:/# lvscan
bash: lvscan: Command not found.
root@WebserverLinux:/# mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=1022487,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1639588k,mode=755)
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=23,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
rpc_pipefs on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=819796k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
root@WebserverLinux:/#
```

Comment: It looks like `sda1` is not an LVM partition type. What are the outputs of `pvscan` and `lvscan`? Also `mount`

Answer (score 0):

> sda1 should be extended with the space from sda4 while server is running.

Doesn't look like that is going to be possible.  The problem is that sda1 doesn't seem to be in LVM, and the space you have for sda4 is not contiguous with the space for sda1.

I am not sure what is going on with sda3.  But if it isn't important and you can delete it, and your system can run without swap temporarily, you might be able to minimize this to a single quick reboot.

1. disable swap `swapoff -a`
2. Delete sda2, sda3, sda4, sda5
3. Delete and recreate sda1, **making sure the starting sector is identical**, and with a new ending that is much larger.  Leave room for a swap filesystem. (or consider switching over to using a swapfile hosted on your root filesystem instead)
4. If using a swap partition, then create a new swap partition following sda1
5. Reboot
6. Do a `resize2fs /dev/sda1`, to expand the filesystem to take advantage of the new space.

P.S.  Make a full backup, or at least take a snapshot in your hypervisor before you start changing anything.

Comment: sda3 was created by mistake when i tied to create the 40gb partition. deleteing the partition doesnt delete the data? i'm little bit confused here =/

Comment: could you chaeck the EDIT in my post wether this is what you ment?

Comment: Your fdisk transcript looks good from what I can see though it would have helped if you had use the (p)rint function before and after you made the partition changes.  But you did get the critical part correct (the start sector).